# How big is inf in swift?

Tags: swift, double, inf

Whenever a value gets higher than 10^220, it gets stored as inf, is there any way around this? Is this true only for Double, which is what I am using in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bigger struct like `Float80` that can store more bits.

There are `Float32`, `Float64` and `Float80` in Swift, where `Float32` is just a typealias for `Float` and `Float64` is one for `Double`.

Also, you can have a link list for storing almost infinite numbers of digits.

Comment: If I have a value, let say 'c', which I want to get larger before it reaches 'inf', if 'c' is actually a Double, could I implement the following to make it work:    var c = Float80('The Double value which c represents')

Comment: @Gabriel don't use `Double` and or `Float80`. Use `Decimal`
 type.